# Replace 7 or more digits from URL but not from at the end of URL in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace 7 or more digits pattern from the middle of a URL. The pattern must have only digits like `/12345678` not like `/1234567ab_et` and not if the pattern is like this `/123456789.jpg`

I am very new in Regular Expression. I have tried with this expression `\/(\d{7,})[^.\d]` but it takes an extra character at the end.

example url: `/uploads/2016/04/1512101244aaaafasdfasdfdas/12345678/a1972_Porsche_911S24Targa-0-1024/234567889.jpg` from this url I just want to replace this `/12345678`

expected url: `/uploads/2016/04/1512101244aaaafasdfasdfdas/a1972_Porsche_911S24Targa-0-1024/234567889.jpg`

Comment: Remove `[^.\d]` from the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried with `[^.\d]` also. It takes all the digits which are more than 7 example: (regexr.com/5992l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you should remove `[^.\d]` and add `\/`, the final regex be like `\/(\d{7,})\/`

The graphical representation of this regex looks like :

[image: regex]

And it works with the url you provided :

[image]

Comment: Great!!! I have got the idea of how to match the final Regex that will work for me from your answer. I will go with this `\/?(\d{7,})\/`

Thanks @Namysh

Comment: Why are you using a capture group? It's useless here.

Comment: @Toto You are right it is useless here but I left it in the case he wants to retrieve the matched id value